# showing a fibonacci series using inserted value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a script that takes the number inserted and use the fibonacci series to show all the numbers until that specific number.

so i already have the fibonacci code, but i can't seem to write the script right so it will take the number inserted. When I use the fibonacci code from the console.log it works perfectly.

This is the script

```js
  var n =$("#num").val();
  $('#shw').click(function(){
      function fibonacci(n){
          var a,b,result;
          a=0;
          b=1;
          result=b;
          for(var i=1; i<n; i++)
          {
              document.write(result+" " );
              result=a+b;
              a=b;
              b=result;
          };
      };
  });
```

```html
 Please Enter Number: <input type="number" id="num" name="num"> <button name="shw" id="shw">Submit</button>
```

I cant take the value inserted and show the fibonacci series until that nth number. The button does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the value of the input inside the listener for the `click` event and eventually call the `fibonacci()` with that value. I have reorganized your code for this:

```js
function fibonacci(n)
{
    var a = 0, b = 1, result = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        document.write(result + " ");
        result = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = result;
    }
}

$('#shw').click(function()
{
    var n =$("#num").val();
    fibonacci(n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Please Enter Number: <input type="number" id="num" name="num">
<button name="shw" id="shw">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @GuySidon You are welcome, consider to accept the answer as correct if this helps you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your var n into the click function. Otherwise n is assigned before the user enters any input

```
<script>
    $('#shw').click(function(){
        function fibonacci(){
            var a,b,result;
            var n =$("#num").val();
            a=0;
            b=1;
            result=b;
            for(var i=1; i<n; i++)
            {
                document.write(result+" " );
                result=a+b;
                a=b;
                b=result;
            };
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `n` to inner function and also call `fibonacci`. In your code you're just defining `fibonacci` but not calling it.

Well a better option is directly assign `fibonacci` to click event.

```js
$('#shw').click(function(){
  var n =$("#num").val();
  function fibonacci(n){
  var a=0,b=1,result=1;
    for(var i=1; i<n; i++){
      document.write(result+" " );
      result=a+b;
      a=b;
      b=result;
    };
};
fibonacci(n)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
Please Enter Number: <input type="number" id="num" name="num"> <button name="shw" id="shw">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your number `n` after the button was clicked!

```js
var btn = $('#shw');
var input = $("#num");

function fibonacci(n) {
  var a, b, result;
  a = 0;
  b = 1;
  result = b;
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    document.write(result + " ");
    result = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = result;
  };
};

btn.click(function(){
  fibonacci(input.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Please Enter Number: 
<input type="number" id="num" name="num"> <button name="shw" id="shw">Submit</button>
```